# Webservice Testing with Specflow (BDD approach)

Tags: web-services, rest, soapui, specflow

Can i test the Webservices using Specflow or in a generic way in BDD form ?

Please share with me some frameworks and/or scripts.

I am new to this whole approach and i am asked to automate the webservice testing using Specflow c#.

Comment: You're asking a very broad question here.  Because your question hasn't been targeted to a specific problem, and you haven't shared any initial research or code in your question, it is impossible to give a high quality answer to your question that addresses the particular problem you are having.

Comment: @perfectionist  As i have mentioned, i am very new to this and i have just been asked if there is any way i can automate the webservices using specflow.  I need some ans which can lead me to a better direction.

Comment: Your post was tagged with SoapUI. Have a look here: http://blog.smartbear.com/soapui/click-using-gherkin-with-soapui/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Specflow can test WebServices - you just need to write the code to do it! What have you tried?

We test our Web Services on a range of Windows and *nix platforms using specflow with a mix of code and scripts to configure and manage our services.

```
Given MyCalculatorService is running 
When I call MyAdditionMethod with 2 and 3 
Then the result is 5
```

"Given MyCalculatorService is running"

- Do everything you need to get you're service up and running
- Might be configuring your service and copying in the latest exe
- Might just be using ProcRunner or similar to start it

"When I call MyAdditionMethod with 2 and 3"

- Connect to the service in the same way you're integrators would.
- This may just be one call or may be a few

"Then the result is 5"

- This may be validating the response from the previous step, or may be making new calls to your service to get the response.

I hope that helps, if not - please add some more details with what you've tried / what you are struggling with.

Comment: Good answer, but I suggest you look into using a tag (like `@CalculatorService`) and then using this tag to bind to a class with `BeforeScenario` and `AfterScenario` steps which setup and tear down your calculator service. See [this blog post](http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/using-tags-in-specflow-features.html) for some examples